# Android image unpack

Tags: custom-roms

How to extract files from vendor_a.img partition inside super.img ?

Super.img file is sparse image and I use simg2img to convert it into raw image, then extract all partition inside.

After checked those partition with commande in linux it's type is data not (ext4 ,ext2, ext3 or erofs)

[image: cmd file extracted/*]

Do my question is how to extract vendor_a.img partition with data type?

Thanks for advance.